# Java: How to store values from .txt into array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that reads grades from a `.txt` file and then outputs the grades in reverse order of the array index.

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.*

public class GradePrint {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));
    int[] grades = new int[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < 30, i++){
        int grade = in.nextInt();
```

How do I take those grades and put them in an array and then print them out in reverse order?

Comment: You should probably try doing your own homework. This site exists to help with problems you have with specific programming questions, not to do your homework for you.

Comment: @EngineerDollery homework questions are *not* a problem here on SO. They just need to state they are homework, and show us what they have tried.

Comment: Yes, but the OP has only posted their homework question, not what they have tried.

Comment: @EngineerDollery fair enough. but your original comment made it sound like hw q's are not ok. just clarifying.

Comment: First of all, what I have stated in the problem is not all of what I have to do for the homework assignment. Second of all, I was stuck on how to store the values into an array which made it difficult for me to continue writing the rest of the program. I appreciate your critism, but I am not asking you to do my homework; I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your grades are in the text file as `10 20 30 40` etc, you can us this code *inside* your `for` loop:

```
int grade = in.nextInt(); //This code is from your code example
grades[i] = grade;
```

To print in reverse order, you can use this `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 29; i >= 0; i--)
{
     System.out.println(grades[i]); //Print out the value at this array index.
}
```

Comment: Thanks this will help me finish the rest of the assignment. I was just confused on how to store the values into an array.

Answer (score 0):

i would not use an array if you do not know ahead of time how many grades you will have in the file.

Instead, try using a `List` like so:

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.*

public class GradePrint {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("data.txt"));
    int[] grades = new int[30];

    for (int i = 0; i < 30, i++){
        grades.add(in.nextInt());
    }
}
```

You will notice two things.

1) I've use the interface `List` and the class `ArrayList`. This is on purpose, since an `ArrayList` is a `List`, this can be done. This provides the benefit that you can change `ArrayList` to something else later on, and so long as it's still a `List`, it will continue to work.

2) `List` provides the benefit of being able to stuff as many elements into it as you want, and it will automagically resize itself without you having to manage it.

To get elements out of your `List`, do:

```
grades.get(i);
```

Where `i` is the position of the grade in the `List`. You can treat a `List` a lot like an array in this regard.

Comment: I know that there are 30 values in the file.

Comment: well, then keep this in mind for the future ;-P ... helps build more robust programs.